# Using widthratio tag properly

Tags: django, django-templates

In my application I need to show in template stocks for my products. So from product view I'm returning variable {{stock}} which is my amount and then I'm trying to use it in template :

```
<div class="bar_in" width="{% widthratio {{stock}} 10 100 %}px" style="background:black;"></div>
```

But it constantly give me "Could not parse the remainder: '{{stock}}' from '{{stock}}' " error. I've tried casting it as int but still the same problem. How to make it work properly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{{ ... }}` is only needed if you want to output the context variable to the template. For tags that can use variables only the name is needed.

```
{% widthratio stock 10 100 %}
```